# Centering 2 divs that may not be always present at the same time CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a CSS for a store.  I need a div that sets the buy button to the left, and a Prev and View Next images to the right, which is working.

My real problem is that sometimes the "buy" button will be not present, because of the PHP.

When the buy button is not present images must be centered, because if they are not, it will be empty space to the left side (where the buy button was)

At first i think on `margin:0px auto`, but this will need a constant width set, right?

I really thought at the beginning this will be very simple. But i got stuck/

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8wXf/)

[Simplified to get the idea](http://jsfiddle.net/vC3At/)

I think im just missing something basic that i cant see know.

HTML:

```
<div id="comprarbtn">
    <div id="wrappcomprarbtn">
        <input class="comprarbtn commonButton" type="button" value="Buy Now" id="buynowlogin">
        <div id="naviminicc"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="prevImg"><img src="images/navmini_01.png" class="navmini1"></a>

            <img src="images/navmini_02.png" class="navmini2" rel="#mies1"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nextImg"> <img src="images/navmini_03.png" class="navmini3"></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.comprarbtn { width:175px; 
  line-height:51px;  
  background-image:url(image.jpg); 
  border:0px; 
  font-size:12px; 
  padding-left:10px; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  text-indent:0px; 
  z-index:10; 
}

#comprarbtn { 
  float:left; 
  position:absolute; 
  width:321px; 
  text-align:center;
  height:51px;  
  z-index:1000;  
  display:table-cell; 
  background-color:#f4f4f4;
}

#wrappcomprarbtn { margin:0px auto;}

#naviminicc { width:145px; float:right;}
#naviminicc a { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
.navmini1 {  cursor:pointer; margin:0px; }
.navmini2 {cursor:pointer; margin:0px; }
.navmini3 {cursor:pointer; margin:0px; }


#navmini { width:135px; max-width:135px;}
```

Comment: Can you post simplified html and css? Way too much going on.

Comment: Yes actually im starting this one, i was looking for an answer, this is very simple indeed.. i will add it to the question http://jsfiddle.net/vC3At/

Comment: fyi, `0px` can be replaced with `0` in css

Comment: not always sometimes just 0 insted of 0px dont work.. i dont remember a particular case, but it happends sometimes to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on with the CSS and HTML you posted, but to achieve what you want to do in theory:

- Give the wrapping div a fixed width large enough to contain both the button and the images
- Give it `margin: 0 auto` to center it and `text-align: center`.
- Make the inner contents `display: inline`

**css**:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 200px; /* Large enough to contain everything */
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper .buttons {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: dont worry i think your right, i just dont get the idea .. Maybe here i can understand what you mean (simplified fiddle with your answer (or what i understand :P) http://jsfiddle.net/vC3At/2/

Comment: Thanks for the Edit i hope you can see the fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/vC3At/2/ bassed on your answer

Comment: Yes, that last fiddle demonstrates it correctly. If you have other elements inside the wrapper div that have 'display: block' you may struggle a bit, so try to keep your HTML as simple as possible with only the bare minimum of what's required.